# Cutting Plain HTML files with RegEX

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, extract, html-encode, utf

I am using this code to extract a part of my locally stored HTML files and save the shortened new document into a .txt file.

```
import glob
import os
import re


def extractor():
    os.chdir(r"F:\Test")  # the directory containing your html
    for file in glob.iglob("*.html"):  # iterates over all files in the directory ending in .html
        with open(file, encoding="utf8") as f, open((file.rsplit(".", 1)[0]) + ".txt", "w", encoding="utf8") as out:
            contents = f.read()
            extract = re.compile(r'(Start).*?End', re.I | re.S)
            cut = extract.sub('', contents)
            if re.search(extract, contents) is not None:
                out.write(cut)
            out.close()
extractor()
```

It works fine for most of my files however for a few files I do have some encoding issues and get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/6930p/PycharmProjects/untitled/Versuch/CutFile.py", line 16, in <module>
    extractor()
  File "C:/Users/6930p/PycharmProjects/untitled/Versuch/CutFile.py", line 14, in extractor
    out.write(cut)
  File "C:\Users\6930p\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 241205-241210: character maps to <undefined>
```

Anyone an idea what's the problem? I thought by using `encoding="utf8"` I won't have any problems with encoding...

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it has been an issue with `encoding="utf8"`. It forgot to encode my new created .txt file with `"utf8"`. Code is updated and works!